# Date compare validator issues

Tags: asp.net, validation, date, datetime

I have date to compare:

Date From = Datetime picker,
Date To = Datetime picker.

I have 2 compare validator in each Datetime picker.
1. Compare validator with operator DataTypeCheck
2. Compare validator to compare Date From and Date To.

Datetime format in my Program is (DD/MM/YYY) (Culture="en-GB")

If I type DateFrom = 15/01/2015 and DateTo = 01/01/2015, The 2nd validator will be executed. "Date From cannot be greater than Date To". (This one is fine)

If I type DateFrom = 32/01/2015 and DateTo = 01/01/2015, The 1st validator will be executed. "Date is not valid". (This one is fine)

But if I type DateFrom = 01/01/2015 and DateTo = 32/01/2015, The 1st and 2nd validator will be executed. "Date is not valid" "Date From cannot be greater than Date To". (This one is the problem)

How to make just 1 validator executed if I type in DateTo?
If I type DateTo = 32/01/2015 the validator just "Date is not valid"

this is my Code

```
 <tr>
                        <td style="width: 96px" class="text">APD Date
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 800px">
                            <asp:TextBox
                                AutoPostBack="false"
                                runat="server"
                                ID="txtAPDDateStart"
                                CssClass="textbox"
                                Width="100px" />
                            <asp:ImageButton
                                ID="imgApprovalDateStart"
                                runat="server"
                                ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar/Calendar.gif"
                                CausesValidation="False" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                                CssClass="textError"
                                ID="RequiredFieldValidator46"
                                ValidationGroup="Submit"
                                runat="server"
                                ErrorMessage="*"
                                ControlToValidate="txtAPDDateStart"
                                EnableClientScript="true"
                                Enabled="true"
                                SetFocusOnError="true"
                                Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="cpvApprovalDateFromValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAPDDateStart" CssClass="textError" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Date is not valid" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="text" Text="To"></asp:Label>
                            <cc1:MaskedEditExtender
                                ID="meeApprovalDateStart"
                                runat="server"
                                TargetControlID="txtAPDDateStart"
                                Mask="99/99/9999"
                                MessageValidatorTip="true"
                                MaskType="Date"
                                AcceptNegative="Left"
                                ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" />
                            <cc1:CalendarExtender
                                ID="ceApprovalDateStart"
                                Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                runat="server"
                                TargetControlID="txtAPDDateStart"
                                PopupButtonID="imgApprovalDateStart" />

                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAPDDateEnd"
                                runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"
                                CssClass="textbox"
                                Width="100px" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgApprovalDateEnd"
                                runat="server"
                                CausesValidation="False"
                                ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar/Calendar.gif" />
                            <cc1:MaskedEditExtender
                                ID="meeApprovalDateEnd"
                                runat="server"
                                TargetControlID="txtAPDDateEnd"
                                Mask="99/99/9999"
                                MessageValidatorTip="true"
                                MaskType="Date"
                                AcceptNegative="Left"
                                ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" />
                            <cc1:CalendarExtender
                                ID="ceApprovalDateEnd"
                                Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                runat="server"
                                TargetControlID="txtAPDDateEnd"
                                PopupButtonID="imgApprovalDateEnd" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                                CssClass="textError"
                                ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
                                ValidationGroup="Submit"
                                runat="server"
                                ErrorMessage="*"
                                ControlToValidate="txtAPDDateEnd"
                                EnableClientScript="true"
                                Enabled="true"
                                SetFocusOnError="true"
                                Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="cpvApprovalDateToValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAPDDateEnd" CssClass="textError" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Date is not valid" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
                            &nbsp;<asp:CompareValidator ID="cpvApprovalDateValidator" runat="server" ControlToCompare="txtAPDDateStart" ControlToValidate="txtAPDDateEnd" CssClass="textError" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Date From cannot be greater than Date To" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use javascript to take a validation for your date
here is the code below:

```html
function ValidateDate1() {
            //debugger;

            var alenddt = document.getElementById('<%= Yourstartdatetextboxid.ClientID %>').value;
            if (alenddt.length == 10) {
                var splits = alenddt.split("/");
                var dt = new Date(splits[1] + "/" + splits[0] + "/" + splits[2]);
                //Validation for Dates

                if (dt.getDate() == splits[0] && dt.getMonth() + 1 == splits[1]

                    && dt.getFullYear() == splits[2]) {

                }

                else {
                    document.getElementById('<%= errormesssageoflabelid.ClientID %>').style.display = 'inline';
                    document.getElementById('<%= Yourstartdatetextboxid.ClientID %>').value = "";
                    hideuser();
                    return;

                }
            }
        }
```

and in this function hideuser code to hide the error label message after 5 seconds

```html
function hideuser() {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                // This will execute 5 seconds later
                var label = document.getElementById('<%=lbMessage.ClientID %>');
               
               
                if (label != null) {
                    label.style.display = 'none';
                }
               
            }, 5000);
        }
```

and call this function from your start textbox like this onkeyup ="ValidateDate()"

same you do for endtextbox so you can see after putting wrong date the textbox text will be blank and message will show invalid date
for your reference check this website: [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Red/Articles/Dynamic-Date-Validation-using-JavaScript.aspx)